# Android studio and git - trouble in collaborating with colleague

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control

I have an Android project on BitBucket that my colleagues and I are collaborating on. The problem is that, whenever I open the project in Android Studio for the first time after cloning, it leaves the local project directory inconsistent with the remote (because of auto-generated files).

In this situation, if my colleague commits any changes and if I try to pull them, git asks me to commit the changes that I have in local. As a result, I have to delete my local repository, clone it, and open it in Android Studio for it can work properly.

I tried using the default `.gitignore` file of Android Studio, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You should avoid committing auto-generated files. For now, try to remove them from the tree once and for all. Then after, you won't see this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the files that are causing a problem to .gitignore, move them to another directory, commit (including deleting the files), then move them back.  Then you should be fine.